# flashing div/strange behaviour with fadeIn() fadeOut() function

Tags: jquery, anchor, fadein, fadeout, behavior

I'm developing an auto anchor jquery plugin with indexing feature for blogger blogs.
This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fd7ee/7/
It's almost done, but i'm having a strange behavior when clicking on one of the headings and then "mostra tutto/show all". The divs, during the fadein start to sort of flashing on and off for half a second.
Also, during the fadein/fadeout effect, the headings overlay the index menu and make it unusable until the animation lasts (you can notice it by the green borders that flashes in front of the index menu).
I'm unable to find a solution for this behavior, what it could be?
thanks again,
Vincenzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `z-index:1;` to your `div.autoanchors` css class, it will work.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fd7ee/8/)

Comment: thanks, this fixed the overlay issue, but there's still the flickering behavior when clicking "mostra tutto/show all", do you have any idea on how to fix it?